# Tunneling AngularJs request for use them in External Api's with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, api, cross-domain

Does anyone know how to perform delegate extaral apis request to rails server instead of doing them in client side in a generic way?

This is needed in order to avoid Cross Domain requests on client side (http://0.0.0.0:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.)

Answer (score 1):

I found a very easy way to do this using Globbing Routes!

In the router:

```
match "api/*url" => "tunnel_api#tunnel_request", via: [:all]
```

And create the controller:

```
class TunnelApiController < ApplicationController
 def tunnel_request
   query_params_string = "?"
   params.each do |key, value|
     unless ((key == "controller") || (key == "action") || (key == "url"))
       query_params_string += key + "=" + value + "&"
     end
   end
   query_params_string = query_params_string[0..-2]
   uri = URI.parse("external_host_url_with_ssl" + params[:url] + query_params_string)
   http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
   http.use_ssl = true
   response = http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri))
   render json: response.body, status: 200
 end
end
```

The tricky part is how to include the query params in the request, so here you can see the loop that I used for creating the query_params_string.
Also remember to handle the different HTTP methods (POST, OPTIONS, …)

I've created a post in my blog for this: http://blog.tcit.cl/post/112616639620/rails-and-angularjs-with-external-api